# Calling at start up time a PWA service that returns a subscription to an observable

Tags: angular, subscription, initializer

I'm trying to have a `PWAService` be called at application startup time. This service returns a subscription:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PwaService {

  constructor(
    private swUpdate: SwUpdate,
    private translateService: TranslateService
  ) { }

  public checkForAppUpdate(): Subscription | undefined {
    if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
      return this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
        const appNewVersion = this.translateService.instant('app.new_version_available');
        if (confirm(appNewVersion)) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

As it returns a subscription, I am inclined to keep the subscription reference so as to unsubscribe later on when the service is no longer needed, that is, when the application is stopped. Even if that stopping might never actually happen, I'm thinking of enabling the unsubscribing anyway.

```
this.swUpdateSubscription = this.pwaService.checkForAppUpdate();

if (this.swUpdateSubscription != null) {
  this.swUpdateSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

It would be handy to use some callbacks like `ngOnInit()` and `ngOnDestroy()` but I don't have any markup to render so there is no template. I therefore don't think I can use a component nor a directive.

I understand I could call my service from the `PWAModule` like:

```
const pwaFactory = (pwaService: PwaService) => () => pwaService.checkForAppUpdate();

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: pwaFactory,
      deps: [ PwaService ],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class PwaModule { }
```

But this above call to `pwaService.checkForAppUpdate()` is not saving the reference to the returned subscription.

How to save this subscription reference so as to later on unsubscribe if needed ?

Also, I don't need this service to be called before the application boot time, it can be called after it has booted. I would like this service not to block and not delay the application boot.

I understand something might not be right in my design and the way I look at the problem.

UPDATE: I could work around the issue and save the subscription in the service. Indeed, the service can have an `ngOnDestroy()` method within which I can perform the unsubscribing:

```
private pwaCheckForUpdateSubscription?: Subscription;

ngOnDestroy() {
  if (this.pwaCheckForUpdateSubscription != null) {
    this.pwaCheckForUpdateSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}

public checkForAppUpdate(): void {
  if (this.swUpdate.isEnabled) {
    this.pwaCheckForUpdateSubscription = this.swUpdate.available.subscribe(() => {
      const appNewVersion = this.translateService.instant('app.new_version_available');
      if (confirm(appNewVersion)) {
        this.uiService.reloadPage();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you call the service method inside the constructor of AppComponent. Using which you can create instance of service at bootstrap and can also unsubscribe at ngDestroy of AppComponent.

Comment: @Prince I would like not to couple the PWA feature to mutch with the app. I'd like to just have to import the PWAModule andnot have to worry about calling the service.